# The best way to configure an unused Ethernet socket (RJ45)

Tags: networking, udev, dhcp

I have a machine (QNAP TS412 ..server, no GUI, indeed no screen) with 2 Ethernet ports. Now the usual setup is I have ETH0 plugged in and getting its address via DHCP, ETH1 empty. But there 2 other real world use cases:

1. I plug in a second Ethernet cable in ETH1
2. I unplug both (needed to cause U-Boot to flash boot instead of BOOTP/PiXE)

Obviously what I like is for all these to work without loads of errors and for example obtain DHCP addresses once cables are plugged in (the machine has no screen or keyboard, usually no serial port access either)

It's a server and I don't want to use networkmanager. I currently have:

```
~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
          hwaddress ether 00:08:9b:cc:cb:cb



root@ts412:~# ls /etc/network/interfaces.d/
root@ts412:~#
```

Which works, but I see:

```
2023-12-17T15:22:58.190680+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
2023-12-17T15:23:01.313988+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
2023-12-17T15:23:07.251521+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
2023-12-17T15:23:16.190124+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
2023-12-17T15:23:29.178166+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
2023-12-17T15:23:46.194142+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
2023-12-17T15:23:59.519262+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: No DHCPOFFERS received.
2023-12-17T15:23:59.528335+00:00 ts412 dhclient[1418]: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Which is just filling syslog with noise ... plus when I plug in ETH1 , there is a long pause before a retry means ETH1 gets an address. This is more significant in the case where I unplug both ETH0 & ETH1, before boot and plug in sometime later ...

It feels like it should be maybe UDEV triggered , so it does not attempt to bring the interface up until a cable is plugged in , them when it is , it immediately comes up and does dhcp.

This feels like it should be common usecase, maybe not so formalised as I'm getting (deliberately unplugging to achieve some result)